# How to Resize Input field in HTML for Apple Devices?

Tags: html, css, ios

My problem is that I have a Website with Input fields and the Input fields works fine on all Devices expect of Apple Devices. I don't know how to fix it.

On a normal Device, it looks like this:
[image: Input Field normal Device]

But on all Apple Devices (Include MacBook) it looks like this:
[image: Input Field Apple Device]

You can't see the Numbers right, and I don't know what I should do.

I hope someone can help me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

It seems a bit difficult but hit and trial approach will be suitable for that.

You should try checking the font that is suitable for both `Android and ios` or exploring font style that is web-based so that you can customize them by applying the desired styling.